# High, opposite estimators in presence of severe multicollinearity - what is the name of the problem?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

Sometimes, when estimating models with two variables affected by severe multicollinearity they both become highly significant with huge estimators of opposite signs. For example +1001 and -1000.

The standard problems of multicollinear data, which may refer to this problem are:

- Increased variance of an estimators.
- Fragility of model to small changes in data and functional form.
- Problems with numerical matrix invertibility when calculating OLS.

None of this situations refers strictly to described phenomenon. I definitivey agree that high estimator variance gives possibility to result in high estimators. But still, the situation is very peculiar and estimators confidence intervals happen to be far far away from zero.

I did not encounter it in popular literature about multicollinearity so my question is how to call such situation? Is it just a form of the problems I described or it has its own name and stories attached to it?

Comment: I don't think it has a name, it's just an effect of multicollinearity.